# Alternating between two branchs in branch specifier in jenkins without pipeline and plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I have a jenkins build that is running on a schedule and  have some logic written in bash, The branch specifier is a parameter passed by the user, i'd like to alternate between two different branches so every other run of the build is  with a different branch specifier , how can I achieve this? I cannot install plugins (lets not go there :) also transitioning to pipeline cannot be done too..
not sure what path to go here but i feel like its still achievable somehow? any ideas?

I haven't tried much because there's no good lead to try, couldn't find anything solid to try

Comment: Check if there is a svn/git/... client installed in the PATH used by the job. If that happens to be the case, just do a manual svn checkout into your workspace from the branch; i.e. do not use the job specific configuration section for the checkout and instead use the shell to do the checkout

Answer (score 0):

> i'd like to alternate between two different branches so every other run of the build is with a different branch specifier, how can I achieve this?

Seems like you need two jobs:

- Job A checking out Branch A at intervals 1, 3, 5, 7, etc
- Job B checking out Branch B at intervals 2, 4, 6, 8, etc